# How to calculate improper integral in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, integral

### How can I calculate the value of this integral:

[image]

f_tu(t) is given as `numpy.array`. The graph looks like this:

[image]

How can I implement this?
Everything I could find looks something like this

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
def f(x):
    return 1/sin(x)
I = quad(f, 0, 1)
```

but I have an array there, not a specific function like `sin`.

Comment: What is the format of the numpy array?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the array you're talking about? The solution could depend upon that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about auc from sklearn.metrics?

```
import numpy as np

import numpy as np

from scipy.integrate import quad

from sklearn.metrics import auc

x = np.arange(0, 100, 0.001)
y = np.sin(x)

print('auc:', auc(x,y))

print('quad:', quad(np.sin, 0, 100))
```

auc: 0.13818791291277366 
quad: (0.1376811277123232, 9.459751315610276e-09)

Comment: I'm still confused about how does OP have an improper integral as an array, though.

Comment: I have not given an integral as an array, given the function `f_tu`. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have one of those pesky infinity integrals. Here is how I would deal with it:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def f(x):
return(1/(x**2)) #put your function to integrate here

print(quad(f,0,np.Infinity)) #integrates from 0 to infinity
```

This returns two values. The first is the estimated value of the integral, and the second is the approximate absolute error of the integral which is useful to know.

Comment: the problem is that you define `f` explicitly, but mine is an array of points. If I just insert my function there, it gives me an obvious error: `ValueError: invalid callable given`

Comment: Why do you want to integrate the improper integral then? Isn't there a maximum value in the array? Do you want to approximate the function and then integrate?

Comment: I’m not sure how to best do it. As I already say the `f` is given me as array in limits [0; 1] with 0.01 step. May be it is better to find as definite integral or maybe I need approximation

Comment: I made another answer that will hopefully work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate a numpy array here is a simple solution:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.trapz(your numpy array here))
```